# Battery Balancing system

Tags: batteries, cell-balancing

I am trying to build a Battery balancer system for 16S8P battery pack.It consist of li-on cells(NCR18650PF). I understood how serial balancing is working properly.If serial cells are not equal,an MCU based system or IC is balancing by the algorithm . But what I dont understand is that should I duplicate 8 times for each individual cell packets? I mean suppose that I designed IC for n serial cell and should I do it for m parallel cell?
I hope it is a clear question.

Comment: Should I add more detail?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking, or even what type of battery you're working with.  Are you asking if each parallel set of batteries needs separate balancing ICs?  Typically no, at least for Li-ion, since when cells are connected in parallel they will self-balance with each other.  But how many you can parallel and how effective the balancing will be will depend on the balancing current you're designing for.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lithium-ion cells like you're planning to use, no, you will not need multiple cell balancing circuits for each set of parallel cells.  The recommended configuration for lithium-ion batteries is to connect each cell group in parallel first, and then string these parallel groups in series.  Within the parallel group, cells will self-balance.  Each group can basically be treated as one large cell.

If for some reason you were to construct serial strings of cells first, and then parallel the whole string, then yes, each string would need its own balance circuit, but this is not advised.

From [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/serial_and_parallel_battery_configurations):

> With Li-ion, the parallel strings are always made first; the completed parallel units are then placed in series. Li-ion is a voltage based system that lends itself well for parallel formation. Combining several cells into a parallel and then adding the units serially reduces complexity in terms of voltages control for pack protection.